# How to Tell If a service Has Been Garbage Collected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, autofac

How I can know if a service has been garbage collected or not knowing that it has been configured as InstancePerLifetimeScope?

```
container.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: The service I registered and that I call in a controller action

Comment: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html#onrelease

Comment: _Disposed_ or _garbage collected_? GC happens at the CLR level, not in Autofac.

Comment: why do you need this information ? what are you trying to resolve ?